# Serialize and Deserialize Map<Object, Object> Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have the following classes that I would like to JSON serialise/deserialise with Jackson (2.9.10) referencing the object using its ID.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Key {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("random_field_key")
    private boolean randomFieldKey;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Value {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("random_field_value")
    private boolean randomFieldValue;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"keys", "values", "relationships"})
public class Relationship {
    @JsonProperty("keys")
    private List<Key> keys;
    @JsonProperty("values")
    private List<Value> values;
    @JsonProperty("relationships")
    private Map<Key, Value> relationships;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```
public class Main {
    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        Value value = new Value();
        value.setId("valueId");
        value.setRandomFieldValue(true);

        Key key = new Key();
        key.setId("keyId");
        key.setRandomFieldKey(false);

        Map<Key, Value> map = new HashMap<Key, Value>();
        map.put(key, value);

        Relationship relationship = new Relationship();
        relationship.setKeys(Collections.singletonList(key));
        relationship.setValues(Collections.singletonList(value));
        relationship.setRelationships(map);

        String serialisedRelationship = mapper.writeValueAsString(relationship);
        Relationship deserialisedRelationship = mapper.readValue(serialisedRelationship, Relationship.class);

    }
}
```

The expected result is the following:

```
{
    "keys": [
        {
            "id": "keyId",
            "random_field_key": false
        }
    ],
    "values": [
        {
            "id": "valueId",
            "random_field_value": true
        }
    ],
    "relationships": {
        "keyId": "valueId"
    }
}
```

Instead, I get:

```
{
    "keys": [
        {
            "id": "keyId",
            "random_field_key": false
        }
    ],
    "values": [
        {
            "id": "valueId",
            "random_field_value": true
        }
    ],
    "relationships": {
        "util.teststack.Key@8646db9": "valueId"
    }
}
```

I added a custom Serializer that allows serializing Key as an Id (I thought the JsonIdentityInfo annotation would take care of that) and managed to get the expected result.

```
public class KeySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Key> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Key value,
                          JsonGenerator gen,
                          SerializerProvider serializers)
            throws IOException {

        gen.writeFieldName(value.getId());
    }
}
```

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"keys", "values", "relationships"})
public class Relationship {
    @JsonProperty("keys")
    private List<Key> keys;
    @JsonProperty("values")
    private List<Value> values;
    @JsonSerialize(keyUsing = KeySerializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("relationships")
    private Map<Key, Value> relationships;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

I can't seem though to deserialise the JSON and I always get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class util.teststack.Key]
```

I though it would've been a good idea to add a custom Deserializer as well, but I'm struggling understanding how to reference an "external" (already instantiated) Key instance. All I can seem to do inside the DeserializerContext is instantiate a new Key, instead of referencing the previously created one.

Inspecting the DeserializerContext I can see that all the instances I need are there, but I don't understand how to reference (and return them).
Surprisingly the reference for the Map Value is working correctly without a serializer/deserializer.

```
public class KeyDeserializer extends com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.KeyDeserializer {

    @Override
    public Key deserializeKey(
            String key,
            DeserializationContext ctxt) {

        Key newKey = new Key();
        newKey.setId(key);

        return newKey;
    }
}
```

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"keys", "values", "relationships"})
public class Relationship {
    @JsonProperty("keys")
    private List<Key> keys;
    @JsonProperty("values")
    private List<Value> values;
    @JsonSerialize(keyUsing = KeySerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = KeyDeserializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("relationships")
    private Map<Key, Value> relationships;
}
```

[Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j47lP.jpg)

I implemented the accepted answer managing to solve the problem this way:

```
public class KeyDeSerializer extends com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.KeyDeserializer {

    @Override
    public Key deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt) {
        Relationship obj = (Relationship) ctxt.getParser().getParsingContext().getParent().getCurrentValue();
        return getKey(key, obj);
    }

    private Key getKey(String key, Relationship obj) {
        for (Key ck : obj.getKeys()) {
            if (ck.getId().equals(key)) {
                return ck;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am curious: since accepting the answer, how did you finally solve it?

Comment: I used the accepted solution to navigate the JSON and retrieve the correct object associated with the key and return it in the KeyDeserializer.

Where should I post the MWE with the working solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the object **DeserializationContext** you are able to retrive your **Relationship** object.

Try something like this

```
ctxt.getParser().getParsingContext().getParent().getCurrentValue();
```

From this object you can retrieve the *instance* you need

Comment: This single-line-solution looks concise and well-formatted. Maybe you could also explain what originally went wrong (missing key-deserializer) and how this line contributes to serializing the key correctly. This would make your answer a __general receipt__ for anyone facing a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try overriding toString() method in your Key class and return the value of "id".

```
public String toString() {
  this.id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to this I can avoid setting the Serializer (instead of getting "util.teststack.Key@8646db9" or similar values I get the actual id), but it still fails deserializing the class.

Comment: Shouldn't you be extending JsonDeserializer<Key> for your deserialization class also? Similar to Serialization?

Comment: You may also remove this
 "@JsonSerialize(keyUsing = KeySerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = KeyDeserializer.class)"

Comment: I've tried removing both annotations but the result is the same. 
I'm extending KeyDeserializer following all the examples I have found online (from baeldung and similar sites) and official documentation.

This allows to avoid deserializing the entire node and focusing on the Map key exclusively. If I were to use a standard deserializer I would have to return the entire property "relationships". I have tried, but I still can't understand how to reference previously instantiated objects from the deserialization context.