# how to resolve object references with a custom Jackson deserializer

Tags: java, json, jackson

```json
{
    "name": "test",
    "columns": [
        {
            "name": "a",
            "type": "TEXT"
        },
        {
            "name": "b",
            "type": "TEXT"
        }
    ],
    "rules": [
        {
            "production": {
                "a": "[b]"
            },
            "filters": {
                "a": [
                    "",
                    "ALL",
                    false
                ]
            },
            "refcolumns": [
                "b"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The JSON document has a property `columns` that contains a Set of `Column` objects (could also be a map using the property name as a key).
This is the only spot where the columns objects are fully serialized in JSON. Everywhere else, columns are referenced using the `name` property that is unique

Reference can be used for map keys and values

I would like to deserialize this document and :

- Resolve the references to their corresponding object in the `columns` property
- Use the same java object **instance** (Column class is immutable) and not create a new `Column`  every time. (I want to reduce the number of objects)

JsonIdentityInfodoesnt work for map keys. So I use custom serializers

Here how is serialized the Rule class,
`JsonColumnKeySerializer` just return the "name" property of Column

```java
class Rule {
    @JsonSerialize(keyUsing = Column.JsonColumnKeySerializer.class) 
    private HashMap<Column, RuleFormula> productions = new HashMap<>();
    @JsonSerialize(keyUsing = Column.JsonColumnKeySerializer.class) 
    private Map<Column, RuleFilter> filters = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "name")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true) // for testing purposes...
    private Set<Column> refcolumns = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess jackson should be able to do it for you, but i couldn't figure out how. As a workaround you can write custom deserializer, in which you can cache the results by name property:

```
public class CachingColumnDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Column> {

  private static final Map<String, Column> MAP = new HashMap<>();

  @Override
  public Column deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JacksonException {
    JsonNode node = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);
    String name = node.get("name").asText();
    return MAP.computeIfAbsent(name, nameKey -> new Column(nameKey, node.get("type").asText()));
  }

  public static Map<String, Column> getMap() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(MAP);
  }
}
```

We need the static instance of the map in order to share it with `KeyDeserializer`, getMap() returns unmodifiableMap so we can't change it by mistake. Then your `KeyDeserializer` will use that map to get existing instances.

```
public class CachedColumnKeyDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer {

  private final Map<String, Column> map;

  public CachedColumnKeyDeserializer() {
    this.map = CachingColumnDeserializer.getMap();
  }

  @Override
  public Object deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
    Column column = this.map.get(key);
    if (column == null) {
      return new Column(key, null);
    }
    return column;
  }
}
```

Specify how to deserialize `Column` class

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CachingColumnDeserializer.class, keyUsing = CachedColumnKeyDeserializer.class)
```

Just to be on the safe side you can specify you need to deserialize columns before other properties

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"name", "columns", ...})
```

Comment: I cannot use a static member as the deserializer is running on a web app. But it works as long as you force the order with JsonPropertyOrder. Any Idea how to share an instance of the Map with a limited scope? I was thinking jackson Value Injection but i don't like it.

Comment: @MiniScalope Why does using static members in a web app worries you? Is it the static map growing over time and causing a leak? Or are the columns unique and immutable only in the scope of a single Rule deserialization and for the next deserialization you need a fresh map?

Comment: There is a lot of reasons. But the main one is that 2 the column names are unique only in the scope of the document. 2 documents can define columns with the same name but different properties.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the solution proposed here [Serialize and Deserialize Map<Object, Object> Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59055918/serialize-and-deserialize-mapobject-object-jackson)

I had to crawl up to the Root parent to find the data.

Compared to the I changed the `Set<Column>` to a `Map<String,Column>`.

```java
public class JsonColumnKeyDeserializer extends com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.KeyDeserializer {
    @Override
    public Object deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        final MyRootClass root = (MyRootClass ) getRoot(context);
        final Map<String, Column> columns = root.getColumns();
        return columns.get(key);
    }

    private Object getRoot(DeserializationContext context) {
        JsonStreamContext parent = context.getParser().getParsingContext().getParent();
        while (parent.getParent() != null && !parent.getParent().inRoot()) {
            parent = parent.getParent();
        }
        return parent.getCurrentValue();
    }
}
```